# ffmpeg nvenc throws an error after I modified an x264 command

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, nvidia-graphics-card, encoding

I'm trying to convert this command to work on nvenc hvec video encoder to just make it faster and utilize my 3060:

`ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[logo];[logo][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.05[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:10[AddedLogo];[AddedLogo]subtitles=subtitles.ass[EndVideo]" -map 0:a -map [EndVideo] -b:v 2400k output.mp4`

This is what i managed to piece together from information found in documentation/forums:

`ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i video.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[logo];[logo][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.05[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:10[AddedLogo];[AddedLogo]subtitles=subtitles.ass[EndVideo]" -map 0:a -map [EndVideo] -c:v hevc_nvenc -fps_mode passthrough -preset slow -b:v 2400k output.mp4 out.flv 2> log.txt`

The nvenc command throws an error (it's cropped to show the error):

```
  Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> scale2ref (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> format:default (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  subtitles:default (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (hevc_nvenc)
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (hevc (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #1:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_subtitles_4 @ 00000237222fa380] libass API version: 0x1701000
[Parsed_subtitles_4 @ 00000237222fa380] libass source: commit: 0.17.0-55-g5c15c883a4783641f7e71a6a1f440209965eb64f
[Parsed_subtitles_4 @ 00000237222fa380] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.13 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 8.1.1 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_4 @ 00000237222fa380] Using font provider directwrite (with GDI)
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_scale2ref_2' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[fc#0 @ 0000023721c200c0] Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while filtering: Function not implemented
[out#0/mp4 @ 000002372237d180] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
[out#1/flv @ 000002372237d6c0] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lq=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=5.24x    
[aac @ 00000237235307c0] Qavg: 65536.000
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command may work:

`ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i video.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_cuda=format=yuv420p,hwdownload[v0];[1:v]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[logo];[logo][v0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.05[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:10[AddedLogo];[AddedLogo]subtitles=subtitles.ass,format=yuv420p[EndVideo]" -map 0:a -map [EndVideo] -c:v hevc_nvenc -fps_mode passthrough -preset slow -b:v 2400k output.mp4`

---

The issue is related to the location where the video frame is stored.

- When using `-hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda`, FFmpeg uses CUDA accelerated decoding (or NVDEC), and stores the decoded frame in the memory of the device (in the GPU).
- The filters `format`, `scale2ref`, `overlay` and `subtitles` are filters that are executed on the CPU (and can't be executed on the GPU).
  Before executing these filters, the frame must be stored in the memory of the "host" (in the memory of the CPU).
- For downloading the decoded frame from device to host, we may use `hwdownload` filter.
  Since the pixel format in the GPU is defined as "cuda", we also have to convert the format to `yuv420p` before `hwdownload`.
  The following applies converting then downloading: `[0:v]scale_cuda=format=yuv420p,hwdownload[v0]`
- We also have to convert the pixel format of the output to `yuv420p` before using `hevc_nvenc` encoder.
  Add `format=yuv420p` after `subtitles=subtitles.ass`.

The equivalent GPU filters to `format`, `scale2ref` and `overlay` are `format_cuda`, `scale2ref_npp` and `overlay_cuda`.
(Using `scale2ref_npp` requires building FFmpeg from sources with NPP library).
`subtitles` filter doesn't have a GPU implementation, so we have to download the frame to the host before using the filter.

The time consuming operations are going to be downloading, filtering in the CPU, and uploading.
Using the GPU for encoding and decoding may not improve the performance dramatically, but that's just the way it is...

Comment: Okay, the command you provided actually works and works really well, it reduces the time needed to decode and encode a video by half. But i have another question, if you dont mind. How could I convert the command from hevc_nvenc to h264_nvenc? Because if you just change `-c:v` value the output video has like 10 frames in total

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue - replacing `hevc_nvenc` with `h264_nvenc` is working in my machine. I am using FFmpeg version 5.1.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev in Windows 10, with NVIDIA GTX 1650. The issue could be related to the version of FFmpeg. The issue could also be related to the GPU driver. I don't know if the input `video.mkv` is related (for testing try other input video). What happens when you use CPU encoding: `-c:v libx264`?

Comment: it was an ffmpeg version issue, the script works with h264 on the newest full build. Thank you very much for your help, i don't know how many hours would it take for me to figure these things out by myself <3